# Should memcpy always be used?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I was working with C and manual memory management and playing around with my code and I noticed this:

Suppose I had

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
int c = 10;
```

If I take these numbers and do this:

```
*a = c;
```

Then `a` will point to a distinct location in memory separate from `c` but will have the value of `c`. If I used:

```
memcpy(a, &c, sizeof(int));
```

The same thing would happen. Distinct pointer, same value.

My question is whether one is preferable to the other? I know for `char *` usually it is `memcpy` or `strcpy` that is used but what about for ints? What about pointers in general? Is assignment ever ok?

P.S. 
I also know that

```
a = &c;
```

will make `a` point to the same memory location as `c` and therefore have its value but I would imagine that would leave a hanging pointer where `a` was since `free` is never called on the memory for `a` so I wouldn't use that.

Comment: You don't get any function call overhead for `*a = c;`

Comment: `memcpy` is generally only used when you can't do a normal assignment, such as copying arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implementation specific. Some compilers, including [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), are able to optimize quite well (with `gcc -O2` at least), calls to  standard functions `memcpy` and to `memset` (which, as my former colleague Pascal Cuoq commented, may be inlined to efficient assignment machine code); sometimes, GCC is even able to optimize some assignment to some structures as calls to `memcpy` (sometimes, calling an efficient `memcpy` routine is faster for large enough `struct`, including for structure assignment; at other occasions, the call to `memcpy`, transformed via some `__builtin_memcpy`, is inlined as an efficient assignment code, perhaps even going thru registers without using any memory)

You could compile your `foo.c` example with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O2 -march=native -S foo.c` then look into the generated `foo.s`

So if you use a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler (or some other good compiler) with *optimizations enabled*, you should **use `memcpy` and `memset`...**

In other words, `memcpy(a, &c, sizeof(int));` can be optimized as efficiently as `*a = c;` (and if you define a "type generic" macro e.g. using [_Generic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) from C99, you would use `memcpy` and it should be optimized efficiently).

Comment: And vice versa, a call such as `memcpy(a, &c, sizeof(int)); ` is likely to be optimized to a couple of instructions that look like they were generated from `*a = c;`.

Comment: Are you saying that they optimize `memcpy` **better** than simple assignment? If the optimized code is equivalent, why do you recommend that they "should use memcpy"?

Answer (score 5):

In your example, you should use `*a = c;` since you only want to copy a single value.
Use `memcpy`, if you need to copy several consecutive elements of an array.

Answer (score 1):

> Should memcpy always be used?

Plain and simple, **no**.

Your first goal in writing code is to make it understandable and maintainable. Everyone knows what `*a = c` will do when `a` is declared as a pointer to an int and `c` is declared as an int. The compiler also knows exactly what you mean by that. You'll never see a compiler optimize your `*a = c` to a call to `memcpy` because that would be a disoptimization.

You will see the compiler optimize `*a=c` to a call to `memcpy` when `c` is of type `struct AVeryLargeStruct` and `a` is a pointer to the same. There's no need to convert `*a=c` to `memcpy(a,&c, sizeof(c))` because the compiler does that for you, *a gratis*. Write `*a=c` because that is clearer than and less error prone than is the `memcpy`.

There are a few places where you truly do need to use `memcpy` (or `memmove`):

- Copying an array,
- Type punning, without using unions, and
- Copying to or from improperly aligned memory.

The first is standard operating procedure; no one will be shocked on reading your code and seeing a call to `memcpy` when used in that context. The latter two are not SOP. Usages of `memcpy` in that context will give readers of your code pause. That's a good thing because you are doing something a bit tricky there. Hiding those tricky calls to `memcpy` amongst thousands of other calls to `memcpy` where you could have used ordinary assignment makes those few places where you absolutely do need to use `memcpy` not stand out. That's a good thing only if your goal is to win the IOCCC.

If you use `memcpy` everywhere you are likely to make your code slower and you are even more likely to make others think there's something wrong with your code.